# What is the correct way from performance perspective to match(replace) every value in every row in temp table using SQL Server 2016 or 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, temp-tables, sql-server-2017

I am wondering what should I use in SQL Server 2016 or 2017 (CTE, LOOP, JOINS,  CURSOR, REPLACE, etc) to match (replace) **every value** in **every row** in temp table? What is the best solution from **performance perspective**?

### Source Table

```
|id |id2|  
| 1 | 2 |  
| 2 | 1 |  
| 1 | 1 |  
| 2 | 2 |
```

### Mapping Table

```
|id  |newid|  
| 1  | 3   |   
| 2  | 4   |
```

### Expected result

```
|id |id2|  
| 3 | 4 |  
| 4 | 3 |  
| 3 | 3 |   
| 4 | 4 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the second table to the first table *twice*:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t1.id AS id_old,
        t1.id2 AS id2_old,
        t2a.newid AS id_new,
        t2b.newid AS id2_new
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2a
        ON t1.id = t2a.id
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2b
        ON t1.id2 = t2b.id
)

UPDATE cte
SET
    id_old = id_new,
    id2_old = id2_new;
```

[image]

### Demo

Not sure if you want just a select here, or maybe an update, or an insert into another table.  In any case, the core logic I gave above should work for all these cases.

Comment: I would suggest using the select as provided above within a CTE, then follow that by the update statement.

Comment: I am also thinking about CTE. Would it be the best solution from a performance perspective? Could you please post an example?

Comment: @DmitryKazakov and `Used_By`, yes a CTE should work fine here.  I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, you did but you should upvote since you got the right idea of question from another answer. Its a good practice. Appreciate one another :)

Comment: @ARr0w Very funny.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `self join` only

```
SELECT t1.id2 as id, t2.id2 
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN table2 t1 on t1.id = t.id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t.id2
```

Comment: While this adds nothing which my answer didn't already say, your query also won't run because the column names don't match the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to apply joins on update query. Something like this:

```
Update tblA set column1 = 'something', column2 = 'something'
from actualName tblA
inner join MappingTable tblB 
on tblA.ID = tblB.ID
```

this query will compare eachrow with ids and if matched then it will update/replace the value of the column as you desire. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may have best performance from solutions posted here if you have indexes set appropriately:

```
select (select [newid] from MappingTable where id = [ST].[id]) [id],
       (select [newid] from MappingTable where id = [ST].[id2]) [id2]
from SourecTable [ST]
```

Comment: I will do a performance test and than choose the right answer. Thank you for your idea.